dynamic programming: (minimum days of not eating icecreams)
Minimum Days Not Eating Ice-cream
Ram decides to eat ice-cream for N days. On each day the ice-cream shop can have chocolate flavour or mango flavour or both or none. The availability of ice-cream flavour is represented as 1 for chocolate, 2 for mango, 3 for both and 0 for none. Ram do not like to have the same ice-cream flavour on any two consecutive days. Find the minimum number of days that Ram do not eat ice-cream.
Boundary Condition(s):
1 <= N <= 100000
Input Format  :
The first line contains the value of N.
The second line contains N integers separated by space(s).
Output Format:
The first line contains the minimum number of days that Ram do not eat ice-cream.
Example Input/Output 1:
Input:
5

1 2 1 0 2
Output:

1
Example Input/Output 2:
Input:

8

2 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 
Output:
2
Explanation:
On the 1st day, ram eats mango flavour.
On the 2nd day, ram eats chocolate flavour.
On the 3rd day, chocolate flavour is available but he cannot eat same the flavour on two consecutive days. So he does not eat anything.
On the 4th day, ram eats chocolate flavour.
On the 5th day, Ram eats mango flavour.
On the 6th day, Ram eats chocolate flavour.
On the 7th day, Ram eats mango flavour.
On the 8th day, Ram do not eat anything.
Hidden case:
I/P:
3001
1 1 0 3 1 3 2 0 3 0 1 2 3 0 2 1 2 2 0 3 3 2 0 3 1 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 3 1 1 3 0 0 3 3 0 0 1 2 0 3 3 3 1 2 1 3 1 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 2 0 3 0 2 2 1 1 2 0 3 1 1 1 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 1 0 2 3 0 2 2 3 1 0 3 2 2 0 1 3 2 0 2 3 3 1 2 2 0 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 2 1 0 3 3 1 3 1 3 0 3 2 3 1 3 3 0 0 1 3 2 3 1 0 3 1 0 2 0 2 3 0 1 3 0 1 3 0 3 3 0 3 2 2 1 1 3 1 0 3 0 0 1 2 2 3 2 1 1 2 0 1 3 1 2 0 1 1 2 1 2 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 1 3 2 3 0 1 3 1 3 1 2 2 3 3 1 3 3 0 0 3 2 3 0 0 2 3 2 0 0 0 2 2 3 2 0 0 1 2 2 0 0 1 1 2 3 3 0 3 2 3 2 3 2 1 0 3 1 3 1 0 0 1 2 1 3 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 1 0 2 0 3 3 3 0 2 0 1 1 3 1 2 2 2 0 0 2 2 1 1 2 3 0 2 0 0 3 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 0 1 2 2 1 0 1 3 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 2 2 3 0 1 1 2 3 1 2 0 3 1 0 0 3 0 3 1 3 1 2 3 0 2 3 0 1 3 0 2 0 1 0 3 1 1 0 3 1 1 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 3 0 1 0 2 3 1 0 0 2 0 1 1 0 0 3 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 2 0 1 3 3 0 0 2 1 3 1 0 0 2 3 1 2 1 0 3 3 0 1 1 1 2 3 0 3 2 0 2 0 3 0 2 3 0 0 0 2 2 2 3 2 0 3 1 2 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 3 2 3 0 1 0 2 3 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 2 2 1 2 3 0 0 3 3 0 1 1 2 0 2 2 3 3 2 2 0 3 3 2 1 0 3 3 0 3 1 1 2 0 2 3 0 0 1 3 1 0 3 2 0 1 2 1 2 3 3 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 2 2 3 1 2 0 2 0 0 1 2 1 3 3 2 3 2 0 2 1 3 0 0 2 2 3 0 2 0 3 0 1 0 0 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 0 1 3 2 3 1 0 0 0 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 0 1 1 3 3 3 0 2 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 3 3 0 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 0 0 2 3 2 3 3 1 1 3 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 3 2 1 3 1 3 3 1 1 0 3 0 3 1 2 2 3 0 0 1 1 2 0 2 0 3 3 1 1 3 1 1 0 0 1 2 3 1 3 1 2 1 1 1 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 2 1 0 2 3 3 1 2 1 3 3 1 1 3 2 3 2 1 3 3 2 3 2 1 3 0 2 3 2 1 2 3 0 0 3 3 2 0 0 1 2 1 0 3 3 2 2 3 0 3 3 0 0 1 2 2 0 0 3 2 2 2 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 3 1 2 0 0 1 1 3 1 0 2 0 3 2 2 2 0 1 2 2 2 1 3 3 3 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 2 2 1 2 2 3 3 3 0 3 1 1 0 2 1 0 1 2 1 2 0 0 3 0 0 3 1 2 3 0 2 0 2 1 0 0 0 2 3 0 3 2 3 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 1 0 2 2 1 1 3 0 3 1 1 2 2 1 3 2 1 1 3 3 1 0 3 3 2 1 3 2 2 2 1 3 0 3 3 3 0 2 0 2 3 1 2 1 2 3 1 3 1 1 3 2 3 0 3 3 1 0 1 3 0 3 2 3 1 3 0 1 2 0 1 3 1 1 1 3 0 0 2 3 3 1 2 1 3 1 3 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 2 2 0 1 3 3 2 0 2 1 0 0 2 3 0 3 1 1 2 0 1 2 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 2 2 2 0 1 0 3 3 3 2 3 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 0 2 2 0 2 3 3 3 0 3 1 0 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 3 1 1 3 2 2 3 2 0 1 2 1 3 1 3 0 1 3 2 2 2 1 2 3 2 1 3 1 0 3 0 3 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 1 0 0 1 2 2 1 0 1 0 3 0 2 2 1 2 0 2 3 1 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 2 3 0 1 0 1 1 0 3 0 3 0 0 2 0 1 2 3 3 1 0 2 0 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 3 2 1 0 3 3 2 0 1 1 1 0 0 2 0 3 2 0 0 1 3 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 0 1 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 3 3 0 3 1 2 3 1 0 3 2 0 2 1 3 0 0 2 2 2 0 3 2 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 2 2 0 3 0 2 3 0 2 1 2 1 1 3 2 0 3 0 1 1 2 0 3 3 0 1 1 0 3 0 0 3 1 3 3 3 0 0 0 3 3 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 3 2 1 1 2 0 2 0 2 3 0 3 1 1 1 0 1 3 2 0 0 1 2 3 2 3 2 0 2 1 0 2 2 2 0 1 3 1 0 0 2 2 1 2 0 0 3 0 1 1 0 3 0 0 2 0 2 3 1 3 1 0 0 0 3 1 2 2 0 3 2 2 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 0 3 2 3 2 2 3 0 1 0 3 0 0 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 1 0 0 1 3 0 0 3 2 3 0 3 0 3 1 2 2 0 0 1 3 3 1 2 1 2 0 1 3 2 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 3 2 1 0 1 0 3 3 0 0 2 2 2 1 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 0 2 3 2 2 3 0 0 1 3 0 2 2 0 1 1 0 3 0 2 2 1 0 2 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 2 0 0 2 1 1 3 3 0 3 3 0 3 0 3 0 0 3 3 1 2 3 3 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 1 2 3 3 1 2 2 1 2 2 3 2 0 0 2 3 1 0 0 1 1 3 0 0 2 1 3 3 3 1 0 2 3 3 3 0 2 0 0 3 3 2 2 1 3 2 3 0 1 1 2 2 0 3 3 2 2 1 3 3 2 3 0 2 0 3 1 1 3 2 3 3 2 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 3 3 1 2 1 2 2 0 2 1 0 0 2 3 3 2 0 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 1 3 0 1 1 3 1 3 3 0 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 3 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 1 3 1 2 2 3 3 1 2 0 1 2 0 2 3 0 0 0 2 1 3 2 0 2 3 0 2 3 1 2 1 1 3 3 1 2 3 2 1 0 2 1 3 3 3 2 2 1 3 3 0 0 3 2 1 2 0 2 2 0 0 3 3 1 1 2 1 0 0 1 0 3 1 0 1 3 1 0 2 0 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 2 0 3 0 0 1 0 3 1 1 1 3 2 1 2 1 3 1 0 1 0 2 2 0 2 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 1 0 2 2 2 1 0 0 2 0 0 3 3 2 0 2 3 2 3 0 2 2 1 0 1 3 1 3 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 2 2 0 1 1 3 0 0 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 0 2 0 2 3 1 3 3 0 2 3 3 3 0 3 1 1 2 3 0 3 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 3 2 2 2 0 2 2 3 1 0 0 0 2 1 3 1 0 1 3 2 2 0 0 1 2 1 2 3 3 0 2 1 0 3 0 2 1 3 1 2 2 2 0 3 2 3 3 1 3 3 0 2 2 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 0 1 0 1 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 0 1 2 0 3 2 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 3 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 2 0 2 3 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 1 0 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 0 0 1 3 0 2 2 1 2 1 2 0 3 3 0 1 2 0 2 3 0 3 1 1 2 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 2 2 1 0 3 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 2 2 0 0 1 3 3 1 1 3 1 3 3 1 1 2 2 3 0 1 1 2 0 1 2 3 3 0 2 3 2 0 3 1 2 1 0 3 0 2 2 2 3 0 2 3 0 2 2 2 0 2 1 3 1 3 3 1 0 3 1 0 0 2 0 3 3 0 3 1 3 2 1 2 2 3 0 0 3 2 0 1 1 2 2 0 0 2 2 1 3 1 1 0 0 3 1 3 2 3 2 1 2 2 3 1 0 2 1 3 1 0 3 3 2 2 0 1 2 1 0 0 2 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 1 1 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 0 3 3 1 2 3 2 3 1 0 1 2 2 1 2 3 1 2 2 0 3 2 3 0 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 2 0 3 2 0 1 3 0 2 0 2 3 3 2 1 1 3 3 3 1 2 2 2 3 1 1 0 1 2 2 2 3 1 0 2 0 0 1 1 1 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 2 2 3 1 0 2 2 0 3 1 2 3 3 3 2 1 0 2 0 1 2 0 1 3 1 3 1 0 2 0 2 3 2 3 1 3 2 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 3 0 1 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 0 3 1 1 2 1 0 0 3 1 0 2 1 1 1 0 2 0 2 0 2 3 3 3 3 3 0 1 2 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 3 2 2 3 2 1 3 1 3 0 1 2 3 3 1 1 1 0 2 3 3 0 2 0 0 0 0 3 3 2 2 3 0 3 1 1 1 3 2 3 2 1 3 0 2 0 3 0 0 3 2 0 2 1 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 1 1 2 1 3 0 2 3 2 2 3 3 1 3 1 2 2 1 3 0 0 2 0 0 3 2 1 1 3 2 2 2 1 3 0 3 0 0 1 2 0 2 0 0 3 1 1 2 1 3 0 2 3 2 0 2 2 1 1 2 3 3 3 0 0 3 3 0 3 3 1 3 1 2 1 2 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 2 1 2 1 0 1 1 3 0 1 0 3 3 1 0 3 3 2 2 1 2 2 0 1 3 2 1 3 1 3 3 3 2 3 0 3 1 1 0 3 0 0 1 0 2 3 2 2 1 1 3 3 3 2 0 1 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 2 2 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 2 2 3 0 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 0 3 2 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 2 3 3 0 3 0 2 2 1 1 2 1 0 0 3 1 3 0 3 1 1 3 3 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 2 3 0 0 2 2 0 1 3 1 3 2 3 1 3 1 0 2 1 0 1 3 1 1 3 3 2 3 0 0 1 3 3 2 1 3 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 2 3 2 3 1 2 1 0 3 1 3 0 1 0 2 3 1 2 2 1 2 1 3 2 3 0 3 3 1 0 1 1 1 3 1 3 1 3 2 0 2 0 1 3 0 2 3 2 2 0 0 2 1 3 0 2 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 0 1 0 2 3 2 3 2 0 1 2 0 1 3 1 3 3 2 0 3 0 2 2 1 1 0 2 3 0 3 1 0 3 0 3 0 1 3 1 3 3 0 0 2 1 0 1 1 2 2 0 0 3 1 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 0 2 0 3 3 2 1 2 1 2 3 0 0 3 1 3 3 1 1 2 0 2 2 3 0 2 3 0 0 1 0 2 1 2 2 0 1 3 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 3 0 2 2 2 1 3 1 1 3 2 0 2 0 1 3 2 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 3 3 1 3 3 2 0 2 1 3 0 3 2 1 1 1 2 2 0 1 3 3 2 0 1 3 0 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 3 1 1 3 3 3 0 3 0 0 2 2 2 0 1 0 3 1 3 3 2 0 2 0 0 1 3 1 0 3 2 1 0 2 3 1 0 1 1 0 2 2 0 2 3 3 3 3 0 0 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 2 1 2 3 0 2 2 0 3 0 3 2 1 0 2 1 0 0 2 3 1 3 3 2 3 1 2 1 2 3 0 0 2 2 3 0 1 2 3 2 3 0 0 3 1 1 1 0 2 3 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 3 0 1 0 2 1 0 3
Expected Output:
1114
Your Program Output:
1126
5 Private (Hidden) Test Cases Failed.
0 Passed
5 Failed
`
CODE:
n=int(input())
ar=list(map(int, input().split()))
dp=n*[-1]
c=0
prev, dp[0]=ar[0],ar[0]
for i in range(1,n-1):
    if ar[i]==prev:
    dp[i]=0
    prev=dp[i]
    continue
    if ar[i]==0:
    dp[i]=0
    prev=0
    continue
    if ar[i]==3 and prev==0:
    if ar[i+1]==1:
       dp[i]=2
    elif ar[i+1]==2:
       dp[i]=1
    prev=dp[i]
    continue
    if ar[i]==3 and prev==1:
    dp[i]=2
    prev=dp[i]
    elif ar[i]==3 and prev=2:
    dp[i]=1
    prev=dp[i]
    else:
    dp[i]=ar[i]
    prev=dp[i]
if prev==ar[n-1]:
    dp[n-1]=0
else:
    dp[n-1]=ar[n-1]
for i in dp:
    if i==0:
    c+=1
print(c)


sorry guys i am newbie to dynamic programming i cant figure out what went wrong.....

Srinivasan, See my answer. I've made in a simpler manner which is easy to understand for new programmers.

This really has nothing to do with dynamic programming.  You just iterating through the array, keeping track of how many days you've skipped, and what you're allowed to eat that day.  Let's use the value 1, 2, and 3 to indicate what you're allowed to eat, in the same way it's used to keep track of what what the store serves.
allowed = 3
skipped = 0
for value in array_of_store_values:
    if value == 0:
        # Nothing there.  I have to skip.  Tomorrow I'll eat anything
        skipped += 1 
        allowed = 3 
    elif value in (1, 2):  # restaurant only has one flavor
        if allowed in (value, 3): 
            # I can eat the restaurant's flavor.  Tomorrow the other
            allowed = 3 - value
        else:
            # No ice cream today
            skipped += 1
            allowed = 3
    else:
        # The restaurant has both.  If I'm allowed to eat anything, then
        # I can delay my decision on what to eat today until I found out what
        # they have tomorrow.  But if I'm only allowed to eat one flavor, 
        # eat it, and tomorrow I have to eat the other.
        if allowed != 3:
            allowed = 3 - allowed

print(skipped)    


I've made a small change in your requirement. As we may need to give more than 1000 elements, it is difficult to count the length of the element. So, I've written in such a way that the program itself will find out the length. We just need to give the input for the value.
l = input()
l= l.split(' ')
N = len(l)
count = 0
for i in range(N):
    x = l[i]

    '''we want to declare l[i-1] as y. But if i ==0, i-1 will become the last elemen
    then. So, if i==0, We declare y i.e i-1 as 3. idea is :If 3 is the previous element,
    the current element value will be considered by the program    
    '''
    if i == 0: y = '3'
    else: y = l[i-1] 
    
    # 1.If x is zero, counted (No ice cream)
    if x == '0': count = count + 1
    
    # 2. If x is not 3 and x == y, counted (No ice cream)
    elif x != '3' and x == y: count = count + 1

    else:pass

print(count)

'''Outputs:
for input: 0 1 0 0 3 2 2 2 0 0 0 1 0 : Output : 9
for input: 1 1 1 2 0 2 2 2 2 1 : Output : 6
for input: 2 3 1 1 3 0 2 0 2 0 2 2 2 : Output : 6
for input: 3 0 0 1 1 3 3 1 3 1 0 2 : Output : 4
for input: 0 2 1 : Output : 1
'''

All the above input numbers were auto generated by another program as follows:
import random as rd 
L = rd.choice(range(20))
s = str(rd.choice(range(4)))
for i in range(L):
    s = s + f' {str(rd.choice(range(4)))}'
print(s)

I did so because all the smaller values can be manually verified. So while verifying manually all the answers are correct. The answer for the bigger number can't be manually verified . Let us see what answer the program gives
for the input =
"1 1 0 3 1 3 2 0 3 0 1 2 3 0 2 1 2 2 0 3 3 2 0 3 1 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 3 1 1 3 0 0 3 3 0 0 1 2 0 3 3 3 1 2 1 3 1 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 2 0 3 0 2 2 1 1 2 0 3 1 1 1 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 1 0 2 3 0 2 2 3 1 0 3 2 2 0 1 3 2 0 2 3 3 1 2 2 0 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 2 1 0 3 3 1 3 1 3 0 3 2 3 1 3 3 0 0 1 3 2 3 1 0 3 1 0 2 0 2 3 0 1 3 0 1 3 0 3 3 0 3 2 2 1 1 3 1 0 3 0 0 1 2 2 3 2 1 1 2 0 1 3 1 2 0 1 1 2 1 2 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 1 3 2 3 0 1 3 1 3 1 2 2 3 3 1 3 3 0 0 3 2 3 0 0 2 3 2 0 0 0 2 2 3 2 0 0 1 2 2 0 0 1 1 2 3 3 0 3 2 3 2 3 2 1 0 3 1 3 1 0 0 1 2 1 3 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 1 0 2 0 3 3 3 0 2 0 1 1 3 1 2 2 2 0 0 2 2 1 1 2 3 0 2 0 0 3 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 0 1 2 2 1 0 1 3 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 2 2 3 0 1 1 2 3 1 2 0 3 1 0 0 3 0 3 1 3 1 2 3 0 2 3 0 1 3 0 2 0 1 0 3 1 1 0 3 1 1 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 3 0 1 0 2 3 1 0 0 2 0 1 1 0 0 3 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 2 0 1 3 3 0 0 2 1 3 1 0 0 2 3 1 2 1 0 3 3 0 1 1 1 2 3 0 3 2 0 2 0 3 0 2 3 0 0 0 2 2 2 3 2 0 3 1 2 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 3 2 3 0 1 0 2 3 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 2 2 1 2 3 0 0 3 3 0 1 1 2 0 2 2 3 3 2 2 0 3 3 2 1 0 3 3 0 3 1 1 2 0 2 3 0 0 1 3 1 0 3 2 0 1 2 1 2 3 3 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 2 2 3 1 2 0 2 0 0 1 2 1 3 3 2 3 2 0 2 1 3 0 0 2 2 3 0 2 0 3 0 1 0 0 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 0 1 3 2 3 1 0 0 0 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 0 1 1 3 3 3 0 2 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 3 3 0 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 0 0 2 3 2 3 3 1 1 3 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 3 2 1 3 1 3 3 1 1 0 3 0 3 1 2 2 3 0 0 1 1 2 0 2 0 3 3 1 1 3 1 1 0 0 1 2 3 1 3 1 2 1 1 1 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 2 1 0 2 3 3 1 2 1 3 3 1 1 3 2 3 2 1 3 3 2 3 2 1 3 0 2 3 2 1 2 3 0 0 3 3 2 0 0 1 2 1 0 3 3 2 2 3 0 3 3 0 0 1 2 2 0 0 3 2 2 2 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 3 1 2 0 0 1 1 3 1 0 2 0 3 2 2 2 0 1 2 2 2 1 3 3 3 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 2 2 1 2 2 3 3 3 0 3 1 1 0 2 1 0 1 2 1 2 0 0 3 0 0 3 1 2 3 0 2 0 2 1 0 0 0 2 3 0 3 2 3 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 1 0 2 2 1 1 3 0 3 1 1 2 2 1 3 2 1 1 3 3 1 0 3 3 2 1 3 2 2 2 1 3 0 3 3 3 0 2 0 2 3 1 2 1 2 3 1 3 1 1 3 2 3 0 3 3 1 0 1 3 0 3 2 3 1 3 0 1 2 0 1 3 1 1 1 3 0 0 2 3 3 1 2 1 3 1 3 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 2 2 0 1 3 3 2 0 2 1 0 0 2 3 0 3 1 1 2 0 1 2 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 2 2 2 0 1 0 3 3 3 2 3 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 0 2 2 0 2 3 3 3 0 3 1 0 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 3 1 1 3 2 2 3 2 0 1 2 1 3 1 3 0 1 3 2 2 2 1 2 3 2 1 3 1 0 3 0 3 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 1 0 0 1 2 2 1 0 1 0 3 0 2 2 1 2 0 2 3 1 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 2 3 0 1 0 1 1 0 3 0 3 0 0 2 0 1 2 3 3 1 0 2 0 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 3 2 1 0 3 3 2 0 1 1 1 0 0 2 0 3 2 0 0 1 3 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 0 1 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 3 3 0 3 1 2 3 1 0 3 2 0 2 1 3 0 0 2 2 2 0 3 2 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 2 2 0 3 0 2 3 0 2 1 2 1 1 3 2 0 3 0 1 1 2 0 3 3 0 1 1 0 3 0 0 3 1 3 3 3 0 0 0 3 3 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 3 2 1 1 2 0 2 0 2 3 0 3 1 1 1 0 1 3 2 0 0 1 2 3 2 3 2 0 2 1 0 2 2 2 0 1 3 1 0 0 2 2 1 2 0 0 3 0 1 1 0 3 0 0 2 0 2 3 1 3 1 0 0 0 3 1 2 2 0 3 2 2 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 0 3 2 3 2 2 3 0 1 0 3 0 0 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 1 0 0 1 3 0 0 3 2 3 0 3 0 3 1 2 2 0 0 1 3 3 1 2 1 2 0 1 3 2 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 3 2 1 0 1 0 3 3 0 0 2 2 2 1 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 0 2 3 2 2 3 0 0 1 3 0 2 2 0 1 1 0 3 0 2 2 1 0 2 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 2 0 0 2 1 1 3 3 0 3 3 0 3 0 3 0 0 3 3 1 2 3 3 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 1 2 3 3 1 2 2 1 2 2 3 2 0 0 2 3 1 0 0 1 1 3 0 0 2 1 3 3 3 1 0 2 3 3 3 0 2 0 0 3 3 2 2 1 3 2 3 0 1 1 2 2 0 3 3 2 2 1 3 3 2 3 0 2 0 3 1 1 3 2 3 3 2 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 3 3 1 2 1 2 2 0 2 1 0 0 2 3 3 2 0 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 1 3 0 1 1 3 1 3 3 0 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 3 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 1 3 1 2 2 3 3 1 2 0 1 2 0 2 3 0 0 0 2 1 3 2 0 2 3 0 2 3 1 2 1 1 3 3 1 2 3 2 1 0 2 1 3 3 3 2 2 1 3 3 0 0 3 2 1 2 0 2 2 0 0 3 3 1 1 2 1 0 0 1 0 3 1 0 1 3 1 0 2 0 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 2 0 3 0 0 1 0 3 1 1 1 3 2 1 2 1 3 1 0 1 0 2 2 0 2 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 1 0 2 2 2 1 0 0 2 0 0 3 3 2 0 2 3 2 3 0 2 2 1 0 1 3 1 3 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 2 2 0 1 1 3 0 0 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 0 2 0 2 3 1 3 3 0 2 3 3 3 0 3 1 1 2 3 0 3 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 3 2 2 2 0 2 2 3 1 0 0 0 2 1 3 1 0 1 3 2 2 0 0 1 2 1 2 3 3 0 2 1 0 3 0 2 1 3 1 2 2 2 0 3 2 3 3 1 3 3 0 2 2 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 0 1 0 1 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 0 1 2 0 3 2 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 3 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 2 0 2 3 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 1 0 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 0 0 1 3 0 2 2 1 2 1 2 0 3 3 0 1 2 0 2 3 0 3 1 1 2 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 2 2 1 0 3 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 2 2 0 0 1 3 3 1 1 3 1 3 3 1 1 2 2 3 0 1 1 2 0 1 2 3 3 0 2 3 2 0 3 1 2 1 0 3 0 2 2 2 3 0 2 3 0 2 2 2 0 2 1 3 1 3 3 1 0 3 1 0 0 2 0 3 3 0 3 1 3 2 1 2 2 3 0 0 3 2 0 1 1 2 2 0 0 2 2 1 3 1 1 0 0 3 1 3 2 3 2 1 2 2 3 1 0 2 1 3 1 0 3 3 2 2 0 1 2 1 0 0 2 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 1 1 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 0 3 3 1 2 3 2 3 1 0 1 2 2 1 2 3 1 2 2 0 3 2 3 0 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 2 0 3 2 0 1 3 0 2 0 2 3 3 2 1 1 3 3 3 1 2 2 2 3 1 1 0 1 2 2 2 3 1 0 2 0 0 1 1 1 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 2 2 3 1 0 2 2 0 3 1 2 3 3 3 2 1 0 2 0 1 2 0 1 3 1 3 1 0 2 0 2 3 2 3 1 3 2 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 3 0 1 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 0 3 1 1 2 1 0 0 3 1 0 2 1 1 1 0 2 0 2 0 2 3 3 3 3 3 0 1 2 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 3 2 2 3 2 1 3 1 3 0 1 2 3 3 1 1 1 0 2 3 3 0 2 0 0 0 0 3 3 2 2 3 0 3 1 1 1 3 2 3 2 1 3 0 2 0 3 0 0 3 2 0 2 1 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 1 1 2 1 3 0 2 3 2 2 3 3 1 3 1 2 2 1 3 0 0 2 0 0 3 2 1 1 3 2 2 2 1 3 0 3 0 0 1 2 0 2 0 0 3 1 1 2 1 3 0 2 3 2 0 2 2 1 1 2 3 3 3 0 0 3 3 0 3 3 1 3 1 2 1 2 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 2 1 2 1 0 1 1 3 0 1 0 3 3 1 0 3 3 2 2 1 2 2 0 1 3 2 1 3 1 3 3 3 2 3 0 3 1 1 0 3 0 0 1 0 2 3 2 2 1 1 3 3 3 2 0 1 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 2 2 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 2 2 3 0 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 0 3 2 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 2 3 3 0 3 0 2 2 1 1 2 1 0 0 3 1 3 0 3 1 1 3 3 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 2 3 0 0 2 2 0 1 3 1 3 2 3 1 3 1 0 2 1 0 1 3 1 1 3 3 2 3 0 0 1 3 3 2 1 3 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 2 3 2 3 1 2 1 0 3 1 3 0 1 0 2 3 1 2 2 1 2 1 3 2 3 0 3 3 1 0 1 1 1 3 1 3 1 3 2 0 2 0 1 3 0 2 3 2 2 0 0 2 1 3 0 2 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 0 1 0 2 3 2 3 2 0 1 2 0 1 3 1 3 3 2 0 3 0 2 2 1 1 0 2 3 0 3 1 0 3 0 3 0 1 3 1 3 3 0 0 2 1 0 1 1 2 2 0 0 3 1 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 0 2 0 3 3 2 1 2 1 2 3 0 0 3 1 3 3 1 1 2 0 2 2 3 0 2 3 0 0 1 0 2 1 2 2 0 1 3 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 3 0 2 2 2 1 3 1 1 3 2 0 2 0 1 3 2 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 3 3 1 3 3 2 0 2 1 3 0 3 2 1 1 1 2 2 0 1 3 3 2 0 1 3 0 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 3 1 1 3 3 3 0 3 0 0 2 2 2 0 1 0 3 1 3 3 2 0 2 0 0 1 3 1 0 3 2 1 0 2 3 1 0 1 1 0 2 2 0 2 3 3 3 3 0 0 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 2 1 2 3 0 2 2 0 3 0 3 2 1 0 2 1 0 0 2 3 1 3 3 2 3 1 2 1 2 3 0 0 2 2 3 0 1 2 3 2 3 0 0 3 1 1 1 0 2 3 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 3 0 1 0 2 1 0 3"
The Output we get is 1120.
As we get proper values for the input upto 20 digits which were manually verified, this 1120 also should be correct because we'll get errors while verifying this much big value manually.
